# Is WebGL able to manipulate sound effectively?

Tags: javascript, audio, actionscript, webgl

I am building a web app which will have 3D objects and much of sound manipulation in real time.
Should I do it with [webGL](http://srchea.com/blog/2013/05/experimenting-with-web-audio-api-three-js-webgl/) or it would be better with actionscript (in a flex project) ?

I am intersted in good performance (many sounds will be played recurrently and in specific times).

An other factor is that I already know Javascript and webGL but not Actionscript, mxml etc.

Listening to your valuable opinion.

Comment: a thing to consider is that Flash/Flex is single threaded , you can get more threads using the new Workers but the implementions of those is a hack in my opinion, so if multi threading is important check this aspect of Flash/Flex

Comment: The app will have many 3D objects, and when they are clicked, they will produce a specific sound and the will continue to produce this sound for ever (let's say). Like if they are entering a loop when clicked. Should I worry about performance in webGL?

Comment: for example, when I used javascript and html elements to play a simple sound in a web page, they had a little latency. Is webGL able to play the sounds recurrently effectively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebGL is not capable of playing sound - however other parts of HTML5 are.

I would highly recommend the [HTML 5 audio api](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/), it will allow you to position a listener and sounds, so played sounds will emanate from different directions (e.g. behind you or beside you).

If you wish to loop your sounds, it's as easy as setting a variable on the source node (the thing that plays the sound).